# Facade of services in Spring

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, facade

I'm working on my first app in Spring and I have a design problem. I've created a few services that I'd like to use through a few facades (is it good idea?). 
I'd like to have structure like this

```
/services
  /facades
    /interfaces
      **facades**
    /implementations
      **sampleFacades**
  /interfaces
    **services**
  /implementations
    **sampleServices**
```

with package-private services (interfaces and implementations). Is it possible or I have to put all classes to one package?

Comment: If you've tried this and you've run into a problem, what was the specific problem you were running into?

Comment: in java com.foo and com.foo.bar are completely separate packages, but I wonder if exists any tricky solution

Comment: Which part did you intend to be package-private? Interfaces cannot be package-private, so what problem do you have with implementations being package-private?

Comment: Let me clarify - **if you've tried this layout**, and you're **actively running into issues with it** in Spring, what are those issues?

Comment: You do understand that facade implementations should only work with service interfaces, not directly with service implementations, right?

Comment: Andreas - services.interfaces.* and services.implementations.*

Comment: Andeas - yes, of course

Comment: Personally I would create package structures representing the domain and not technical constructs like interfaces and implementations, cf [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). In this case you would put the implementations in the same package as the interfaces. This is a design choice though and opinions vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Facade Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) is meant to create a simplified and dedicated access to more complicated code.

Typically you would have an API created by someone else and you would then create your own custom API to consume the other.

In this case you seem to be creating façades to Services in within the same Spring Applicaiton, which to me does not really make sense.

**Why create façades when you have control over the service definitions?**

If there is a need for a façade for your own service, perhaps they are not defined at the right level of granularity?

Note that some of the complexity of the Services should be addressed by other patterns such as [Data Access Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) coordinated by the Services.

Regarding your question on putting all the classes in the same package, consider the Bounded Contexts of [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) and organize your code around the domain instead of implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I agree, that was architecture mistake.